# Supply credentials to $http GET Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am invoking an API from angular JS front end and I am getting the 401 Unauthorized error. Here are the options I have tried.

Option 1:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password')
    },
    url: 'http://localhost:11000/api/ping'
}).then(function(r) {
    return Session.userId = r.headers('user');
})
```

Can you please help me in passing the credentials to backend API?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code by checking the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to see what headers are sent?

Comment: Are you using ASP .Net forms authentication?

Comment: Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8000
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 04 Jan 2016 21:19:46 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Vary:Origin
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring"

Comment: Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:11000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/app/
user:samuel

Comment: No Avi, I am not using .Net forms.

Comment: @Avi, ASP.NET Forms Authentication doesn't use Basic Authentication.

Comment: Additional Info, I have tried accessing the API by SoapUI and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you make an $http request you have to use a promise because of the asynchronus

```
function httpReq (){
    return $http({ // this will return a promise
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log('success');
        return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log('error');
        return response;
    });
}
```

and how to use the promise returned by the function

```
httpReq().then( function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Aliainlb. Just curious, why I am getting 401 error on the API layer?

Comment: i don't know why sorry. try a google search with "401 angular $http"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230417/capture-http-401-with-angular-js-interceptor

Comment: I have tried this option and no luck. Still I am having the same 401 error.