# getting status -1 instead 401 Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, akka

I'm trying to get a response from server. The function looks so:

```
function getOverview() {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: base,
            headers: {
                'authorization': 'Bearer ' + GottenTokens.getSessionToken()
            }
        };

        return $http(req).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                return response;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            });
    }
```

When the status is 200, there's no problem, it returns the good response with status 200. But... when the status is 401, than it returns a response with status -1:

```
Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

I was trying it in postman and I saw there's the status 401 and also in browser it says so:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/overview. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

It means that the browser and postman take the status from server, but it doesn't come in Angularjs. I was trying this post: [Capture Http 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230417/capture-http-401-with-angular-js-interceptor) but it doesn't help me. I have that function in a "factory".

By the way, the server is written in akka. I don't know if it has something to do. Before was it in NodeJS and I didn't have problems. Since it's in akka I can't get the status in Angularjs.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing cross-site requests, the server has to add to ALL responses a valid CORS header. This includes error responses like 401.

Make sure you can see the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` header in your 401 response, it's most likely missing.

Comment: Yes, it was :) Thanks!