# Why is the response with error code (500) treated as successful response while using interceptor

Tags: angularjs, http, response, interceptor

I am trying to use an Angular interceptor for handling my `500` or `403` error codes. For other codes I have custom business implementation. However it seems using interceptor makes Angular treat error responses as success responses and my success callback in `.then` is called. Isn't this strange, considering docs which says 200-299 codes are only treated as success response.

My code:

```
function appInterceptorFn(){
        var interceptor = {
            responseError: function (config) {
                if (config && config.status === cramConfig.FORBIDDEN_ACCESS_CODE) {
                    $rootScope.$emit('ERROR_EVENT', config);
                }
                return config;
            }
        }

        return interceptor;
    }
```

Is there something that can be done to avoid it, I am using `AngularJS v1.3.17`

I have visited this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230417/capture-http-401-with-angular-js-interceptor) which shows a different implementation but I would like to use interceptor preferably.

Is this a known issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by returning your object "normally", you tell angular to treat your error as a success.

You have to replace your

```
  return config;
```

with

```
  return $q.reject(config);
```

**Explanation**

If you look at the documentation here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors , you will see the following:

```
// optional method
'responseError': function(rejection) {
   // do something on error
   if (canRecover(rejection)) {
     return responseOrNewPromise
   }
   return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

I know it's not a lot of documentation, but it tells you that if you return an object, or a promise, it will resolve your error as if there was no error. If you want your error to be re-thrown, you have to do it explicitly by using `$q.reject()`

Comment: Which promise do I reject. Do I have to make a promise out of the in-bound response object.