# Integrated Windows authentication to avoid 401 prompt and show custom login

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, browser, windows-authentication

we have angularjs spa application. which calls asp.net web api with windows authentication. If user not logged in (401) browser prompt for credential.

But I need to show custom login page on 401. Can someone help on it.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230417/capture-http-401-with-angular-js-interceptor

Comment: That said, I'm assuming you know that if your static resources require auth right now, you'd have to update that (ie. IIS) to allow them first.

Comment: I set http - withCredentials: true in angular and from iis and web api [ checking windows authentication] and returns 401 if not logged in. And browser shows credential prompt automatically. I don't want that and need to show custom page.